# Using a star character (*) in File.GetLastWriteTime returns error using c#

Tags: c#

I want to get the last modified date and time of a file. For this I found `System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime()`. If I want to use it it returns the error that I got an illegal character in my path.

I got this code:

```
string otherPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + @"\test\";

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime datetime = File.GetLastWriteTime(otherPath + "*.txt"); // Here the error comes up

    if (Directory.GetFiles(otherPath, @"*.txt").Any() && datetime == DateTime.Now)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Folder has .txt file and was last modified today");
    }

    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Folder has .txt file and was not last modified today");
    }
}
```

If I remove the `*` character it works. But then I can't define all files with ending `.txt`. Is there another way to do it? I already tried `@"*.txt"` but this doesn't work neither.

Suggestion appreciated :)

Comment: What do you expect? What if it finds more than one file?

Comment: You can't use File.GetLastWriteTime for any files at some path. You should get all files in the folder, then get last write time for each of it and only then you could get the maximum date to use for your folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use a wildcard character in `Path.GetLastWriteTime`(as in `Directory.GetFiles` for example). It must be a valid path to a single file.

Use `System.IO.Path.Combine` to create a valid path.

```
string path = Path.Combine(otherPath, "FileName.txt");
DateTime datetime = File.GetLastWriteTime( path );
```

Since `otherPath` is a folder is assume that you want to use:

```
DateTime time = Directory.GetLastWriteTime(otherPath);
```

If you instead want to check if any text file in the folder was changed today:

```
string[] fileNames = Directory.GetFiles(otherPath, "*.txt");
if (fileNames.Any(fn => File.GetLastWriteTime(fn) >= DateTime.Today))
{

}
```

Comment: Oh, okay. And is there another way instead of `File.GetLastWriteTime`? If I got dynamic file names in a folder which changes everyday how can I check these?

Comment: Therk, you could get the list of file names in a directory any time using Directory.GetFiles(otherPath, @"*.txt"). It returns List<String> with file names.

Comment: @Therk: so you want to know if any text file in the folder was changed today? Have a look at my last edit.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter Thank you :) I try it

Comment: @Tim Schmelter it works, thank you. But can you please explain me the `fn => File.GetLastWriteTime(fn)` part? What does the `=>` mean?

Comment: That's a lambda expression, which is the core functionality of LINQ. A lambda expression is an anonymous function that can contain expressions and statements, and can be used to create delegates or expression tree types. All lambda expressions use the lambda operator =>, which is read as "goes to". The left side of the lambda operator specifies the input parameters (if any) and the right side holds the expression or statement block.

Comment: Ah nice to know. I will read more about, it sounds interesting and useful. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

That's because `*` is a reserved character and cannot be used in a filename.

You appear to be trying to use `*` as a wildcard. Indeed that is why the character is reserved - so that it can be a wildcard. But you cannot use a wildcard with a function that returns information about one single file. What would you expect the function to do if multiple files matched?

I think what you probably need to do is enumerate all matching files with your wildcard, and request information about each matching file. You are looking for either `Directory.GetFiles` or `Directory.EnumerateFiles`.